# How to refresh a variable upon resizing the browser using Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I grab the size of a slide image using `let size = carousel_images[0].clientWidth;` and `clientWidth` varies in different viewports, here, `carousel_images` is pointing to `img` within the `.carousel` and here is how it varies in different viewports:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .carousel {
    max-width: 994px;
    img {
      min-width: 994px;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel {
    max-width: 1150px;
    img {
      min-width: 1150px;
    }
  }
}
```

so when I resize the browser it looks like:

[image]

but as I refresh the page, it looks normal again.

[image]

here is full code pen [link](https://codepen.io/basirpayenda/pen/mdJqBaR?editors=1100), Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
    size = carousel_images[0].clientWidth
    carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size}px)`
})
```

Essentially, you need to listen window `resize` event, update variable and execute code again wherever that variable is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign a new value to your `let size`. Is it a global variable? Perhaps, putting it inside a function or class is a good idea.

You could use the resize event, which fires when your window changes size.

The following demo is from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

```js
const heightOutput = document.querySelector('#height');
const widthOutput = document.querySelector('#width');

function reportWindowSize() {
  heightOutput.textContent = window.innerHeight;
  widthOutput.textContent = window.innerWidth;
}

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

```html
<p>Resize the browser window to fire the <code>resize</code> event.</p>
<p>Window height: <span id="height"></span></p>
<p>Window width: <span id="width"></span></p>
```